# Angular. Calling method of component from another component update model, but don't update the view of called component

Tags: angular, view, model

Experimenting with ngx, noticed such feature: when trying to call method of component from another component, it updates model but doesn't update the view of called component.

The situation is next: in html of root.component have test.component. View of test.component should be changed by calling method of that component from any other component.

```
app.component.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<test-comp></test-comp>
```

Test.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'test-comp',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent {
  public isVisible: boolean = false;

  public setVisibility(isVisible: boolean) {
    this.isVisible = isVisible;
  }
}
```

Test.component.html

```
<div>
  <p>Test component is visible: {{isVisible}}</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isVisible">
  <p>Hi, this is test component!</p>
</div>
```

In some other component calling corresponding method of test.component:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor (private testComponent: TestComponent) {}
  .....................................................
  this.testComponent.setVisibility(true);
```

}

In debugger I can see that model is changed (`this.isVisible = isVisible;`), but model isn't updated.

So, I know that it's a very bad approach to call method of component from another component, but I'm interested in details: why view in this case isn't updated ?
And Is there a way to update view for that situation ?

Thank you, guys !

Answer (score 1):

Try using a *ViewChild()*, declare it before constructor within your parent component:

```
@ViewChild(TestComponent) testComponent: TestComponent;
```

Call from parent to child component:

```
this.testComponent.setVisibility(true);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your response !                                                            
Yes, it works fine, but only for the situation when TestComponent is a child for component from which we want to call method of TestComponent...                                                                                   
 But what is about the situation when TestComponent isn't child (sibling, for example)  ? )                                                                                                               Thank you !

Comment: In this case, do not forget that 'child component' should affect parent's parameter, not sure how exactly you are using it, but that would be the first place I would look at. Also make sure that the child component's function is public and is accessible from the 'outside'

Comment: Looking at your code I notice that you are doing _this.isVisible = isVisible;_ in **TestComponent** this will affect _**only**_ __isVisible_ of child component. If you want to change it in **LoginComponent** I would add a _return this.isVisible_ and assign it to a new parameter in Parent component. If any of the suggestions were helpful I'd appreciate it if you could select this answer as the correct one :)